# Makings arrays out of a class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I made a class called juice so I can make an array of of that class, and then I set the array to 50, and set the price of the juice to the index. The problem is, when I tried to print out the price of juice[7], which is suppose to be 7, since that's the index, it prints out 49 instead. I don't know what I did wrong. Please kindly point out my mistakes. Thank you.

```
package juice;



public class Juice {

static String size;//size of the juice
static int price;//price of the juice

Juice(String size, int price) {
    this.size = size;
    this.price = price;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MakeJuice.makeJuice();

}

}

class MakeJuice {

static Juice juice[] = new Juice[50];

static void makeJuice() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        juice[i] = new Juice("Big", i);//set price to the index
    }

    System.out.println(juice[7].price);//print out the price of juice[7],...supposely, which is suppose to be 7, not 49.
}

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

size and price should not be static. That will fix your problem.

Comment: Okay. That did fix the problem. Thank you. Can you kindly tell me why static makes it not work?

Comment: Static makes the variable global to that class instead of instance specific. Rather than creating new instances with unique size/price variables, you were just updating the single instance. Further reading on the nature of static propertyies/methods in Java may be helpful.